# How to publish Angular 1.5 module written in TypeScript on NPM properly?

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, typescript, npm, webpack

I am trying to publish an NPM module to consume it with Webpack in another project. The module is written in TypeScript and contains an Angular 1.5 module. So far I've come up with something like this:

```
import {ExampleDirective} from './example/ExampleDirective';
import {ExampleComponent} from './example/ExampleComponent';
import {IExampleInterface} from './example/IExampleInterface';
import {ExampleFilter} from './utils/ExampleFilter';
import {ExampleClass} from './example/ExampleClass';
import {ExampleService} from './example/ExampleService';

// export everything that you want to access directly in TS code outside the package
export {
    IExampleInterface, ExampleClass, ExampleService
}

// add to the module everything that should be available via Angular DI mechanism
angular.module('my.components', [])
    .directive('example1', ExampleDirective.factory())
    .component('example2', new ExampleComponent())
    .filter('example3', ExampleFilter.filter)
    .service('ExampleService', ExampleService);
```

The file above is called index.ts and imports/exports all of the TS code to consume. Then I've got the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-components",
  "version": "0.0.6",
  "main": "lib/index.ts",
  "typings": "lib/index",
  "files": [
    "lib/"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "typings install && tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.*",
    "lodash": "4.13.*",
    "moment": "2.14.*"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.*",
    "font-awesome": "4.6.*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "1.8.*",
    "typings": "1.3.*"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "lib"
  },
  "files": [
    "src/index.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

and typings.json:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "angular": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/angularjs/angular.d.ts#060060dc34ef700a6ea9e00ccee69b570ff3c242",
    "lodash": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/lodash/lodash.d.ts#83f954972eea14a29161a0d9b9e602c4f8f824d1",
    "moment": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/moment/moment.d.ts#56295f5058cac7ae458540423c50ac2dcf9fc711",
    "moment-node": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/moment/moment-node.d.ts#8886ae591751e8a8237fa855617745768f0b1bdf"
  }
}
```

When I run npm publish, everything is compiled from /src folder and JS code along with TS definitions is located in /lib folder as desired. After publishing, I'm able to use the directives and components in my HTML templates and inject services.

There is however one problem: when I need to import my TS definitions anywhere I need to import it like this:

```
import {ExampleClass, IExampleInterface, ExampleService} from 'my-components/lib/index';
```

instead of for example:

```
import {ExampleClass, IExampleInterface, ExampleService} from MyComponents;
```

This is not a big deal, but it makes writing code harder, because my IDE (IntelliJ Ultimate) can't figure out the auto importing. How can I modify the index.ts file to allow for easy importing? I couldn't find any tips or conventions in NPM/TypeScript/typings/Webpack documentation. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: index.js + index.d.ts should do the trick. `@angular/core` package is a pretty nice reference. Take a look also at [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules) and [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typings-for-npm-packages.html) chapters. I guess that the alternative is to have index.ts in package root that will reexport the package.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately I wasn't able to fix it even after reading the TS documentation. Angular team is using some custom annotation (@NgModule) on the class that they are exporting, so I guess it's not helpful here. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: [It is specific to A2 apps](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html), it loosely equals to `angular.module` and affects nothing on package level. TS decorators are transpiled to .js + .d.ts in the end. For A1 it is conventional to export `name` prop from Angular modules as `default` export.

Comment: @mc.suchecki Did you manage to make it work? By any chance, do you have the (public) codebase for this project?